# Cloning Windows from HDD to SSD with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I wanted to clone my Windows 7 from an 60GB HDD to a 250GB SSD.

I put the SSD on SATA3, booted Ubuntu from a USB flash driver, cloned in GParted via cCopy/paste and flagged the partition bootable.

Then I removed the HDD from SATA1 and switched the SSD from SATA3 to SATA1.

When I then booted from the SSD, I got an error message that a required device was not found. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You've only copied partition layout, not the content. And if you have BIOS-style boot in place, even partition content wouldn't be sufficient, because there's some extra boot code that needs to be preserved.

You can use Clonezilla to do all of this automatically for you. It's available in Ubuntu if you enable additional software sources. You can download the [ready-made ISO](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) as well.

Comment: any tool other than clonezilla?!

Comment: @Max What exactly are you looking for that Clonezilla doesn't offer? Are you cloning a BIOS or UEFI system?